# How to make an opaque UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I wanted to create an opaque button  with text at the right corner in the button for my application. I tried following ways to achieve the opacity but could not get the opacity.

With below approaches I was getting white button against the background

```
1.      UIButton *Button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
        Button.frame = CGRectMake(offset, height/4, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        [Button setTitle:ButtonLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:Button];

2.  CALayer *layer = Button.layer;
    layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```

I know this is possible duplicate, but nothing is working from the suggestions given in the links

Also please suggest how to set title in below right corner of button.

Comment: If you want an opaque button, why are you giving it a background of [UIColor clearColor] ?

Comment: [UIColor clearColor] will make your button transparent. just remove that one and you can get opaque button

Comment: I have tried to use the alpha value but didn't succeed. Do you have any suggestions how to go for opacity

Comment: I agree I have used clearColor before for transparency but in the above code its not even getting transparent but its getting white against the black background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **`opacity`** , you can set the `setAlpha` property of the `UIButton`

For text alignment, you can use `contentHorizontalAlignment` and `contentVerticalAlignment`

**Here is the edited code:**

```
UIButton *Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
Button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 100);
[Button setTitle:@"myButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[Button setAlpha:0.42];
Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
Button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:Button];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIButtonTypeCustom` buttonType when you don't need special style of RoundRect, InfoDark, etc. You'll be able to add border color and/or round corners with Quartz

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

_button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
_button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
_button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
_button.layer.borderWidth = 1;
_button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

just create the button with custom type instead of `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
```